# Is there a way to show Nested Structure of JUnit 5 in Maven Surefire Report? or any other HTML report alternatives?

Tags: java, maven, report, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using JUnit 5 to create dynamic test cases in a nested structure. (So test cases are grouped). However when I run 'mvn test site' to create the HTML report. It only gives me the display names of the test inside the groups. The Dynamic Container names are nowhere to be found in the reports. Is there a way to configure this in the pom.xml file? or maybe an alternative HTML report plugin that can show me how many test cases fail per Dynamic Container? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this recently and was forced to the conclusion that the only way is to write a custom report by implementing a TestExecutionListener (see junit5 docs - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-reporting)

There is of course the Open Test Reporting XML format which just outputs all the events including the hierarchy and you can use that